# Building Sass files in Ant doesn't work from Eclipse

Tags: java, ruby, eclipse, windows, ant

We are migrating the CSS files in our Java webapp over to Sass. Currently we are using Ant to build our project and we have managed to create a target which will run Sass on our SCSS files. The target works as expected on OSX through Terminal, on Windows 8 and 8.1 through Command Prompt (when Ruby has been correctly added to PATH), the OSX version of Eclipse and through the Windows version of IntelliJ IDEA when using the Ant Build feature. The problem is that it doesn't work when run through the Windows version of Eclipse. Whenever we try and run an Ant build through Eclipse we get the following error:

```
[apply] ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- C:/Dev/project/sass (LoadError)
```

If I change the path of Sass.bat to "C:\dev\ruby\bin\sass.bat" it works but I would like to avoid this as it means that each developer will need to update their copy of the Ant file to point to their ruby/bin folder.

I suspect that there is an extra step in Eclipse that needs to be performed to correctly set up Ant but I'm struggling to work out what the problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I've just added this. At least its only fixed for windows users.

```
<condition property="sass" value="C:/Ruby22/bin/sass.bat" else="sass" >
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```